# How to exclude hidden/system sharepoint files when enumerating a document library

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

I'm trying to enumerate all the files in a SharePoint document library but I want to exclude things like the forms and the document templates, plus any other unexpected items that are not normally shown on the AllItems view.

When using explorer view they appear as hidden files or folders so I want to be able to ignore them somehow.

```
    IEnumerable<SPFile> GetAllSubContent(SPFolder spFolder)
    {
        foreach (SPFile spFile in spFolder.Files)
        {
            yield return spFile;
        }

        foreach (SPFolder spSubFolder in spFolder.SubFolders)
        {
            foreach (SPFile spFile in GetAllSubContent(spSubFolder))
            {
                yield return spFile;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are hidden files/folders the only thing you want to exclude?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How to exclude system files using SharePoint OM

**Option 1**

Use [SPFile.Item Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile.item%28v=office.14%29.aspx) to exclude system files (those files that does not belong to a document library):

```
var isSystemFile = (file.Item == null);
```

Example:

```
IEnumerable<SPFile> GetAllSubContent(SPFolder spFolder)
{
    foreach (SPFile spFile in spFolder.Files.Cast<SPFile>().Where(f => f.Item != null))
    {
       yield return spFile;
    }

    foreach (SPFolder spSubFolder in spFolder.SubFolders)
    {
        foreach (SPFile spFile in GetAllSubContent(spSubFolder))
        {
           yield return spFile;
        }
    }
}
```

**Option 2**

Using CAML query:

```
IEnumerable<SPFile> GetFiles(SPList list, SPFolder folder)
{
    var query = new SPQuery {Folder = folder, ViewAttributes = "Scope=\"Recursive\""};
    var items = list.GetItems(query);
    return from SPListItem item in items select item.File;
}
```

Usage:

```
var list = web.Lists.TryGetList("Assets");
var files = GetFiles(list, list.RootFolder);
foreach (var file in files)
{
      Console.WriteLine(file.Name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks tried Option 1 and it works well, I can't see how Option 2 actually ignores files where the .Item is null though. Would option 2 be faster than option 1, although I think this isn't going to be the bottleneck of my solution anyway.

Answer (score 1):

To exclude hidden files, you can do a linq query on the list of files and filter out any that have `FileAtttributes.Hidden` set e.g:

```
 IEnumerable<SPFile> GetAllSubContent(SPFolder spFolder)
    {
        var filteredFileList= spFolder.Files.Select(x => x).Where(x => (x.Attributes & FileAttributes.Hidden) == 0);

        foreach (SPFile spFile in filteredFileList)
        {
            yield return spFile;
        }

    }
```

If you want to exclude certain filetypes, you  can use this:

`var filteredFileList = Directory.GetFiles(spFolder).Where(name => !name.EndsWith(".exe")); \\or whatever extension you want to exclude`

Comment: Thanks that's good but I'm going to give the answer to Vadim as it more closely covers what I asked.